# Как взять значение из INPUT'а

Tags: javascript

Всем привет. Подскажите, как забрать значение из `INPUT`'а. Такой код не работает:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var text = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
    var val=text.innerHTML;
    alert(val)
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="#"><input type="text" value="Some text here..." />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Firebug говорит: `text is undefined`

Comment: `document.forms[0].elements[0].value` и у вас хтмл невалидный несмотра на обилие загогулин

Comment: @karmadro4-ер, ты на лету проверил валидацию? Ты ошибку в JavaScript-е назвал загогулиной?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var text = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
var val = text.value;
alert(val);
```

Comment: @Deonis, не помогло... Та же ошибка.

Comment: [смотрите живой пример](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/Etyst/)

Comment: Да, точно. Так и есть.

Answer (score 5):

Попробуйте

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
      var text = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
      var val=text.value;
      alert(val)
  </script>
```

перенести после формы. Или обернуть в onLoad.

Comment: И вам спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function getValue(){
    var text = document.getElementById("input_form").value;
    alert(text);
  }
</script>
................................
<input type="text" id="input_form" value="Some text here..."  />
<input type="submit" onclick="getValue()" />
```